# Validate Youtube url in sitecore

Tags: sitecore9

I'm new with sitecore 9.0 and want to add validation on a field to check if the value entered in this field is only  youtube url , I know that it must match regular expression but how to add this in sitecore ?? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to create a new validation rule and then apply it to your field at a data template level.
For example, if you want to validate your numeric value by a regular expression  like *^(\d{6,12})$* then you will need to:

1. Create a new Validation Rule in */sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/* folder with *Sitecore.Data.Validators.FieldValidators.RegexValidator,Sitecore.Kernel* Type and 
   specify your regular expression in *Parameters* field
   [see an example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kA9f.png)
2. Apply the validation rules to the required field by selecting your newly created Validation Rule in *Quick Action Bar*, *Validate Button*, *Validator Bar* properties under the *Validation Rules* section for your specific field in the corresponding data template
   [see an example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hupjt.png)

From now on you can validate your data input during editing, for example via Preview -> Validation action in Sitecore menu.

Comment: You can also use a regular expression in the "Validation" field of the field's settings in the Content Editor, without needing to create additional validation rules.